# How to disable javascript scrolling on websites?

Tags: scroll

Some websites hijack the normal scrolling behavior (I assume they do it through Javascript, here is an [example](http://astutegraphics.com/blog/30-must-free-illustrator-scripts-2/)), which makes my trackpad become hypersensitive. Is there a way to disable this and use the browser default?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the link provided with Safari, Chrome and FireFox Dev Edition. Neither of them show this behavior.

Despite the question is clearly off-topic, why not just disable JS in our Browser?